# UITableView Edit mode

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, editmode

I have `UITableView` and I am trying to load it by default in edit mode. The problem is  when I this line `table.editing=TRUE;` my rows disappear, I implemented this methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
 return NO;
 }
```

but with no luck. What should I do?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

as ***Anish*** pointed to using

```
[tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
```

But you need to have it in `viewWillAppear` view event to make it work.

Comment: Yes this worked but made my right button disappear. How could i stop this.

Comment: you mean `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`? why don't you also try adding it in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: No.I mean that i had a button where you could move to another page.

Comment: It existed in normal mode.I mean the accessory button.

Comment: are you adding `[cell.editingAccessoryType   = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate?

Comment: You need to have a look to this [editingAccessoryType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/editingAccessoryType)

Answer (score 10):

try this...

```
[tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
```

Comment: No luck. I also tried realoding data after setting the edit mode: [table reloadData];

Comment: have a look at here...http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 7):

**In ViewDidLoad write**

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addORDoneRows)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
```

**addORDoneRow**

```
- (void)addORDoneRows
{
    if(self.editing)
    {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [_dbSongsTblView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [_dbSongsTblView reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [_dbSongsTblView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [_dbSongsTblView reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
    }
}
```

**For MultipleSelection of Row**

```
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

**Note: There are Three Editiing Style as below**

```
UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone,
UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete,
UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert
```

**Note: And for multiple Selection set Selection and Editing Style to Multiple from Attribute inspector**

Comment: was there a reason to call `reloadData`? In my case it isn't, apart that disables the animation when entering/exiting from edit mode

Answer (score 2):

To load a tableView in edit mode you should call `setEditing(true, animated: false)` in `viewDidLoad()`.

If your view controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController` there's no need to change, just make the above call. Otherwise if your view controller is a subclass of UIViewController, then you should make a call in this way: `tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)`.

*Tested with Swift 2.2.*

Answer (score 0):

[self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.isEditing animated:YES];