# How to separate left-view/ textview iOS 7 ?

Tags: ios, iphone, textfield, separator

Is that possibile to use this design from some apple's library for textfields?

[image]

it is the standard editable textfield on native ios 7 contacts. And if it's not possible, how to use a separator between leftview and textfield like in this picture?

Comment: That looks more like a `UITableViewCell` then a `UITextField`. Are you sure it's a `UITextField`?

Comment: look in "contacts" app of your iphone/ipad/simulator, open a contact and press "edit" at the right top of the screen and you will see :)

Comment: Yep - that is definitely a `UITableViewCell` not a `UITextField` or `UITextView`. Have a look at some of these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001852/uitableview-edit-mode http://behindtechlines.com/2012/06/enabling-configuring-uitableview-edit-mode/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591121/uitableview-cell-edit

Answer (score 0):

those separators are just views but with width 1 pixel  and height equal to height of cell.

```
UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,0,1,30)];
view.backgroundColor =[uicolor lightGreyColor];

[add it as subview to your view]
```

Comment: No it's not. That is a `UITableView` in edit mode -1.

Comment: yes sir.but he asked "And if it's not possible, how to use a separator between leftview and textfield like in this picture?". so there is my answer for it.

Comment: It's still wrong. If they are wanting to use that design that is in the contacts app when you press edit then they need to be implementing a `UITableView` that allows the user to edit the cells. Just adding your own `UIView` in is incorrect, they clearly didn't know what they were actually looking for/at so best thing to do is to correct them, also what's `uicolor`? It should be `UIColor`

Answer (score 0):

there no create by default apple SDKs but you achieve like customize your table view cell

[Sample App](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCTextFieldCell)

[image]

Comment: Why would you need to use a third party to achieve this? This can be got by the default behaviour of `UITablViewCell` and `UITableView`.

Comment: they example tell how to we are customize the tableViewCell thats all @Popeye

Comment: See I didn't get that as your answer doesn't say anything like that. Maybe you should tell them how to it yourself. As this just says to me here is some third party code you can use when it isn't really needed.

Comment: and can I have at least the separator between leftview and textfield without the implementation of a text view?

Comment: It's not a text view please look at `UITableView` implementation.