# How to animate UITableViewCell transition for all cells in a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view that has an 'editing' mode and a normal mode. When the cell is in an editing mode, it has different layout constraints. All cells goes into editing mode simultaneously. I want to animate the transition in all cells from non-editing mode to editing mode and vice versa. How can I animate these all simultaneously?

I have seen advice like this: [UITableView Edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001852/uitableview-edit-mode) However if I apply that I get my custom editing mode layout PLUS the built in OS editing mode, which I don't want. How can I transition to only my editing layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think the one way to do that is

- add a variable like `isEditing` to your VC
- when a cell goes editing mode - you set `isEditing` true
- reload tableview content
- animate cell in `cellForRowAt` right after initialization if `isEditing` is true

Maybe you need to elaborate this considering the editing state not to animate cells newly initiated by scrolling.

Here is the snapshot of the code I quickly put:
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pb166c1mokgf2e/Untitled.mov?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but I don't think I follow. When I reload the table view content, the table view content will already immediately appear (unanimated) in the 'editing' mode whereas I want to show a smooth transition.

Comment: That's why you need to animate your cell manually right after initialization.